# Store a file inside an object

Tags: java, file, upload

I have a Java client/server desktop application, where the communication between client and server is based on Sockets, and the messages exchanged between client and server are serialized  objects (message objects, that incapsulate requests and responses).

Now I need to make the client able to upload a file from the local computer to the server, but I can't send the File through the buffer, since the Buffer is already used for exchanging the message objects.

Should i open another stream to send the file, or is there any better way to upload a file for my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I need to make the client able to upload a file from the local computer to the server`

**-** Open a `Solely Dedicated Connection` to the Server for File uploading.

**-** Use `File Transfer Protocol` to ease your work, and moreover its quite easy and reliable to use the `Apache's common lib` for **File uploading and downloading**....

**See this link:**

http://commons.apache.org/net/

Comment: I'm gonna investigate the FTP library tomorrow, it seems promising

Answer (score 1):

You really only have two options:

1. Open another connection dedicated to the file upload and send it through that.
2. Make a message object representing bits of a file being uploaded, and send the file in chunks via these message objects.

The former seems simpler & cleaner to me, requiring less overhead and less complicated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your solution and pass the file content as an object, for example as a String - use Base64 encoding (or similar) of the content if it contains troublesome characters